# Why not getting the plot using NSolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, code-request

I am trying to plot using these equations in NSolve but not getting any graph. I don't know why it is happening. Usually, these types of equations solved easily but I don't know where I am doing the wrong step.
If anyone can resolve this is most welcome.

```
P0 = 1;
ee = 1;
ome = .46;
kc = .1;
deld1 = 2;
deld2 = 2;
kd = .2;
del1 = deld1 - kd;
del2 = deld2 - kd;
ome1 = 12.45;
ome2 = 12.45;
alpa = 0.2;
g0 = 0.4;
sol = NSolve[{(del1 + del2 + alpa)*C0e12 + ome1*C1g1e2/2 + 
      ome2*C1e1g2/2 + g0*C1e12 == 
     0, (delc - kc)*C1g12 + ome1*C0e1g2/2 + ome2*C0g1e2/2 + 
      g0*Sqrt[2]*C2g12 + g0 + P0 == 0, 
    del1*C0e1g2 + ome1*C1g12/2 + g0*C1e1g2 == 0, 
    del2*C0g1e2 + ome2*C1g12/2 + (g0 + P0)*C1g1e2 == 
     0, ((delc - kc) + del1)*C1e1g2 + ome1*C2g12/Sqrt[2] + 
      ome2*C0e12/2 + (g0 + P0)*C0e1g2 == 
     0, ((delc - kc) + del2)*C1g1e2 + ome1*C0e12/2 + 
      ome2*C2g12/Sqrt[2] + g0*C0g1e2 + P0*C0g1e2 == 
     0, ((delc - kc) + del1 + del2 + alpa)*C1e12 + (g0 + P0)*C0e12 == 
     0, ((delc - kc)*C1g12 + ome1/2)*C0e1g2 + ome2*C0g1e2/2 + 
      Sqrt[2]*g0*C2g12 + (g0 + P0) == 
     0, (Sqrt[2]*(delc - kc) - I*ee/Sqrt[2])*C2g12 + 
      ome1*C1e1g2/Sqrt[2] + ome2*C1g1e2/Sqrt[2] + 
      I*ee/Sqrt[2] + (alpa*Sqrt[2] + P0*Sqrt[2])*C1g12 == 0}, {C0e12, 
    C1g12, C0e1g2, C0g1e2, C1e1g2, C1g1e2, C1e12, C1g12, C2g12}];
P1 = Plot[{Evaluate[(Abs[C2g12]^2)/(Abs[C1e12]^2 + 
         Abs[C2g12]^2)^2] /. sol}, {delc, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False,    
  FrameLabel -> {Style[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalDelta]\), \(c\)]\)", Bold, 30], 
    Style[" \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(2\)]\)(t)", Bold, 30]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["(a)", Bold, 25],  
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 25], 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0005], Thickness[0.005]}]
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the braces `{}` from around the `Evaluate`?

Comment: The problem is not in the plotting. Your NSolve returns `{}`, indicating that it finds no solutions. `delc` is undefined in your code, and it is not among the variables for which you are solving. NSolve is a numerical solver, so every parameter must be assigned a value. Even Solve indicates no solutions though. I'd check your equations to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
P0 = 1;
ee = 1;
ome = 23/50;
kc = 1/10;
deld1 = 2;
deld2 = 2;
kd = 1/5;
del1 = deld1 - kd;
del2 = deld2 - kd;
ome1 = 249/20;
ome2 = 249/20;
alpa = 1/5;
g0 = 2/5;

eqns = {(del1 + del2 + alpa)*C0e12 + ome1*C1g1e2/2 + ome2*C1e1g2/2 + 
      g0*C1e12 == 
     0, (delc - kc)*C1g12 + ome1*C0e1g2/2 + ome2*C0g1e2/2 + g0*Sqrt[2]*C2g12 +
       g0 + P0 == 0, del1*C0e1g2 + ome1*C1g12/2 + g0*C1e1g2 == 0, 
    del2*C0g1e2 + ome2*C1g12/2 + (g0 + P0)*C1g1e2 == 
     0, ((delc - kc) + del1)*C1e1g2 + ome1*C2g12/Sqrt[2] + 
      ome2*C0e12/2 + (g0 + P0)*C0e1g2 == 
     0, ((delc - kc) + del2)*C1g1e2 + ome1*C0e12/2 + ome2*C2g12/Sqrt[2] + 
      g0*C0g1e2 + P0*C0g1e2 == 
     0, ((delc - kc) + del1 + del2 + alpa)*C1e12 + (g0 + P0)*C0e12 == 
     0, ((delc - kc)*C1g12 + ome1/2)*C0e1g2 + ome2*C0g1e2/2 + 
      Sqrt[2]*g0*C2g12 + (g0 + P0) == 
     0, (Sqrt[2]*(delc - kc) - I*ee/Sqrt[2])*C2g12 + ome1*C1e1g2/Sqrt[2] + 
      ome2*C1g1e2/Sqrt[2] + 
      I*ee/Sqrt[2] + (alpa*Sqrt[2] + P0*Sqrt[2])*C1g12 == 0} // Simplify;
```

Note that you typed `C1g12` twice in the `NSolve` variables. It is better to extract the variable names.

```
vars = Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]]

(* {C0e12, C0e1g2, C0g1e2, C1e12, C1e1g2, C1g12, C1g1e2, C2g12, delc} *)

Length /@ {eqns, vars}

(* {9, 9} *)
```

You have nine equations with nine unknowns so all variables are determined and the expression to be plotted has constant values.

```
sol = Solve[eqns, vars];

Length@sol

(* 10 *)

expr = N[(Abs[C2g12]^2)/(Abs[C1e12]^2 + Abs[C2g12]^2)^2 /. sol, 20] // N

(* {71.2109, 0.196351, 0.00146171, 28.5873, 65.5947, 0.000106435, 
 4.55254*10^-8, 23.5583, 1.53393, 1745.38} *)
```